# Is there any testing framework like Selenium for automation of windows 7 desktop application?

Tags: software-testing

I have been using Selenium for web testing and now there is some part of the project that requires me to interact with desktop application on windows 7. Is there any tool/framework like WinAppDriver that can be used on windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You want the excellent, and free, [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

It is not explicitly a testing language, but can certainly be used as one. It lefts you simulate mouse & keyword input and very screen activity.

Here’s a simple script which opens Notepad, writes to its input and saves the file:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Save")
;WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Do you want to save") ; When running under Windows XP
Send("!n")
```

You can test with e.g.

> AutoItWinGetTitle Retrieves the title of the AutoIt window.

call that and test the value.

See a complete list of built in functions [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Function_list) and decide if it is for you. I think you will be pleased. I know that I have been, for decades.